# Differentiability of a complex function of a complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the points at which the function f(z)=|sin z|, z is a complex variable, is differentiable. 
The existence and continuity of the partial derivatives of the given function are easy to prove. But checking the equality of the Cauchy Riemann equations at the points is very cumbersome. Could anyone give me an elegant way of solving this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $\sin(z)\neq 0$, then
$$
\overline{\sin(w)}=\frac{|\sin(w)|^2}{\sin(w)},
$$
for all $w$ in a neighborhood of $z$. Therefore, $\overline{\sin}$ is holomorphic at $z$ if $|\sin|$ is.

The case $\sin(z)=0$ can be handled separately by studying the limit of the incremental quotient.